# Transparent custom UIView takes 4 times longer to draw in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, core-graphics

I originally wrote my app for iOS 7, but am now trying to get it to run in iOS 8. Everything works as expected, but in iOS 8 it uses dramatically more CPU time than in iOS 7. I've narrowed the problem down to drawing transparent custom UIViews; a minimal example project which shows the problem can be found at the following link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jscytdh1dyoiot/testProject.zip?dl=0. It contains only a single custom UIView which is a child of the view controller's main view, and whose background is transparent. The view controller uses a display link to call this view's (empty) drawRect on display refresh.

In my testing, this uses more than 40% of the CPU in iOS 8, compared to around 10% in iOS 7. Output from Xcode's Time Profiler shows a call to "_platform_memset" in "CGBlt_fillBytes" taking up most of the CPU time. What is this, and (more importantly) how can I get back to the iOS 7 performance? Any help is much appreciated – this problem is totally ruining my app!

iOS 7:
[image: iOS 7 performance]

iOS 8:
[image: iOS 8 performance]

Comment: Can you track the original code which run on the thread?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean exactly?

Comment: I've updated the question with some new information. It seems that the drawRect of transparent UIViews is the culprit... but how do I fix it?!

Comment: did you ever make any progress with this?

Comment: It seems to be an iOS 8 bug. I asked this question on the Apple developer forums, and was advised to submit a bug report, which I did. I also submitted a technical support request, and was told that the Apple engineers had "determined that you are experiencing an issue for which there is no known workaround at this time." It still hasn't been fixed – in fact, the problem seems even worse on 8.3 (now using close to 80% of CPU).

Comment: I ended up having to rewrite my drawing code to eliminate drawRect altogether (I'm now doing everything with a combination of OpenGL and UIImageViews). It was a lot of work, but there was no alternative in my situation.

Comment: Are you seeing this problem too? I was always surprised that I seemed to be the only person with the issue. What hardware are you using?